# Resolving Apple Mach-O Linker Error in swift and xcode 6.4 beta

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uistoryboard

My main.storyboard got accidentally deleted and when I re-added it to my project from the trash, I started receiving 27 Apple Mach-O Linker Errors. I think that it has something to do with my Parse/Stripe integration however I wasn't getting any of these problems prior to the deletion of my storyboard. If anyone could tell me how to love this or where I should look. I am not getting any compile error in any of my self-made classes. Furthermore, when building my project, before the errors are found I get 4 Apple Mach-O Linker Warnings which say that some directory isn't found. Many thanks

Comment: Have you tried to clean and rebuild? ("Clean" on the "Product" menu or Shift-Cmd-K)

Comment: yes I have and that hasn't worked. I have also deleted my derived data. @Narkyator

Answer (score 0):

You might have to import your libraries inside to make sure it's all being referenced properly ie #import "header.h". Aside from that maybe make sure the O-linker has necessary  -frameworks. Hope it's some help.